# Install of pycrypto [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: debian, software-installation

I am installing [this tool](https://github.com/threatstream/mhn)  to Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 x64 (wheezy) and when I run `install_mnemosyne.sh` I get this error when the pycrypto installation is running:

```
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB): 446kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py"
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/instal
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1
    do_download,
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1
    self.session,
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", l
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/opt/mnemosyne/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line
    destfp.close()
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

But `df -i` shows this:

```
Filesystem                                               Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs                                                    85344  20381    64963   24% /
udev                                                     214285    350   213935    1% /dev
tmpfs                                                    216800    287   216513    1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/aa26072b-e0f4-4962-ba44-76d5e65346de    85344  20381    64963   24% /
tmpfs                                                    216800      3   216797    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                    216800      2   216798    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda9                                              35323904    576 35323328    1% /home
/dev/sda8                                                 97536    270    97266    1% /tmp
/dev/sda5                                                549440  57132   492308   11% /usr
/dev/sda6                                                183264   8085   175179    5% /var
```

and `du -sh /*`:

```
6,0M    /bin
16M     /boot
0       /dev
3,5M    /etc
14M     /home
0       /initrd.img
94M     /lib
12K     /lost+found
3,0K    /media
1,0K    /mnt
158M    /opt
19M     /pokus
0       /proc
294K    /root
808K    /run
5,6M    /sbin
1,0K    /selinux
1,0K    /srv
0       /sys
6,7M    /tmp
1,7G    /usr
2,2G    /var
0       /vmlinuz
```

If I run `df -i` during installation increase is about 1%:

```
  Filesystem                                               Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
    rootfs                                                    85344  20381    64963   25% /
    udev                                                     214285    350   213935    1% /dev
    tmpfs                                                    216800    287   216513    1% /run
    /dev/disk/by-uuid/aa26072b-e0f4-4962-ba44-76d5e65346de    85344  20381    64963   25% /
    tmpfs                                                    216800      3   216797    1% /run/lock
    tmpfs                                                    216800      2   216798    1% /run/shm
    /dev/sda9                                              35323904    576 35323328    1% /home
    /dev/sda8                                                 97536    270    97266    1% /tmp
    /dev/sda5                                                549440  57132   492308   11% /usr
    /dev/sda6                                                183264   8085   175179    5% /var
```

But `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                                                Space Used Free Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                     323M  311M     0 100% /
udev                                                        10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                      406M  832K  405M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/aa26072b-e0f4-4962-ba44-76d5e65346de     323M  311M     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                      5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                      2,4G     0  2,4G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda9                                                  531G  211M  504G   1% /home
/dev/sda8                                                  368M   18M  332M   5% /tmp
/dev/sda5                                                  8,3G  1,9G  6,0G  24% /usr
/dev/sda6                                                  2,8G  2,3G  402M  85% /var
```

So how can I expand rootfs please?

Comment: Is that df-i from while you are running the install, or after it?

Comment: @user82286 After unsuccessful installation...

Comment: You can run out of diskspace long before running out of inodes, does `df -h` indicate sufficient empty space on your rootfs?

Comment: @user82286 during installation increase is about 1%...

Comment: @HBruijn I have added df -h output to main post, so rootfs is full... How can I expand it please?

Comment: Perhaps you can delete this question, as it has become irrelevant, and open a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output of your `df` commands you're running out of disk space on your root partition, which is the reason why installing your software package fails with the descriptive error: `IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`.

Try installing your software in larger partition like `/usr` with sufficient empty space instead of `/opt` which is on your tiny and full rootfs.

Regardless your solution should at least consist of creating some free space on the root filesystem,  as a full rootfs is bad.

The majority of  the majority of the root filesystem seems to be occupied by the contents of `/opt`, maybe you can move that directory to another partition and create a symlink in its place?

Because you're using hard partitions and not something more flexible like LVM resizing the root partition appears a bit difficult, so I don't have an easy solution at hand.

You have a sizeable disk (600GB or larger even based on /home), why did you limit the root filesystem to 300 MB in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunatelly I have got this server with preinstalled system... :-( So I think that symlink will be the best solition for me. I need create symlink to `/opt` and `/opt` move to /home. So first I will move `/opt` to `/home/opt` and next I create symlink `ln -s /home/opt /opt`?

Comment: Yes, that should work